# Change text id span via JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need change "Výrobce" in this span:

```
<span class="p-cat-manufacturer">Výrobce:<span itemprop="brand">Jamie</span></span>
```

**I try this:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ $('.p-cat-manufacturer').html('Dodavatel:'); });   
</script>
```

But this code replaces all text with span.

Comment: sorry span, no div

Comment: One straightforward solution would be to get the existing html content of the outer element, use the string `.replace()` method to change that text, then set the html to the updated text.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca That code will replace *everything* in the span.  The question is quite clear.

Comment: @Archer so they mean they don't want the innermost `span` to be overwritten? Is that the sense of the question?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Yes